# How can I remove the duplicate links from this Python code?

Tags: python

How can I remove the duplicate links from this Python code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import bs4

search_link = "https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/state-total.html"
r = requests.get(search_link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a')

file = open('testfile.txt','w') 

for link in results:
    S=link.get('href')
    file.write("%s \n" % S)

file.close()
print(len(results))

import csv
for link in results:
    S=link.get('href')
    csvRow = [S]
    csvfile = "data.csv"
    with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(csvRow )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code replace:

```
for link in results:
    S=link.get('href')
    file.write("%s \n" % S)
```

with:

```
existing_links = {}
for link in results:
    S=link.get('href')
    # Write link only if it wasn't writed before
    if S not in existing_links:
        file.write("%s \n" % S)
        # Momorize link
        existing_links[S] = True
```

Comment: in both case it pulls 647 links, i believe it should pull less when you remove the duplicates.

Comment: This number says nothing about duplacate links. Maybe where aren't any? What amount of links are in the testfile.txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` over the `href` retrieved values:

```
for s in set(map(lamba x: x.get('href'), results)):
    file.write("{}\n".formate(s))
```